# Javascript live code modification

Tags: javascript, debugging, live

I'm new to javascript and I want to ask if there is any way to modify javascript code that was loaded from the server side? There is an external script `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`
Can I modify this, let's say with Google Chrome inspector. I want  to alter for example, one of the script's functions. Can I do it?

Comment: I tried to alter the source script from google debugger, even pressed Ctrl+ S , and it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong :)

Comment: I do it all the time. You just have to make sure the code you save is actually being run again, saving it won't cause all the code in a file to be run See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItMcQyXrWF8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

However, if you refresh (or the script is requested again) you'll get the original script from the server.

Answer (score -4):

JavaScript cannot be modified on the client. Think of the havoc this would cause if you could.

Comment: Yes it can, Chrome dev tools lets you edit the source files and hotswap them http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItMcQyXrWF8

Comment: Wow. That's interesting. Thanks Juan.